# How to test if a file has been created by pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

Is there any way of checking if a file has been created by `pickle`? I could just catch exceptions thrown by `pickle.load` but there is no specific "not a pickle file" exception.

Comment: Check for traces of vinegar and dill

Comment: Are you worried about whether a file has been *created* when you just used `pickle.dump`, or about whether a file exists when you use `pickle.load`? In either case, the error would happen when you are opening the file handle for output or input, not in the actual `pickle` line.

Comment: I'm not worried about whether the file exists or not but about whether a file that exists has been created by `pickle`.

Comment: Thanks for this question. It inspired me to finally look at what pickle files actually are. There are several protocols (pickle file formats) -- see PEP 307 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/) -- the first was ASCII and subsequent ones are binary, with incremental improvements. Protocol 3 is only available for Python 3. 

As far as I could find out, none have a isfileapicklefile type check, but there several useful Unpickling exceptions (as @Ned-batchelder promotes in his answer): http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.UnpicklingError

Comment: Sounds like you are in a pickle!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pickle files don't have a header, so there's no standard way of identifying them short of trying to unpickle one and seeing if any exceptions are raised while doing so.

You could define your own enhanced protocol that included some kind of header by subclassing the `Pickler()` and `Unpickler()` classes in the `pickle` module. However this can't be done with the much faster `cPickle` module because, in it, they're factory *functions*, which can't be subclassed <sup>[1]</sup>.

A more flexible approach would be define your own independent classes that used corresponding `Pickler()` and `Unpickler()` instances from either one of these modules in its implementation.

**Update**

The last byte of all pickle files should be the `pickle.STOP` opcode, so while there isn't a header, there **is** effectively a very minimal trailer which would be a relatively simple thing to check.

Depending on your exact usage, you might be able to get away with supplementing that with something more elaborate (and longer than one byte), since any data past the `STOP` opcode in a pickled object's representation is ignored <sup>[2]</sup>.

<sup>[1]</sup>  [Footnote [2]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#id12) in the Python 2 documentation.
<sup>[2]</sup>  Documentation for`pickle.loads()`, which also applies to `pickle.load()`since it's currently implemented in terms of the former.

Answer (score 12):

There is no sure way other than to try to unpickle it, and catch exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue and found a fairly decent way of doing it. You can use the built in pickletools module to deconstruct a pickle file and get the pickle operations. With pickle protocol v2 and higher the first opcode will be a `PROTO` name and the last one as @martineau mentioned is `STOP` the following code will display these two opcodes. Note that output in this example can be iterated but opcodes can not be directly accessed thus the for loop.

```
import pickletools

with open("file.pickle", "rb") as f:
    pickle = f.read()
    output = pickletools.genops(pickle)
    opcodes = []
    for opcode in output:
        opcodes.append(opcode[0])
    print(opcodes[0].name)
    print(opcodes[-1].name)
```

Comment: Yeah, protocol 2 through 4 start with 0x80 followed by the protocol number (https://peps.python.org/pep-3154/. e.g. PyTorch pickle files start with [0x80,0x02].