# EOFError: Ran out of input when unpickling non-empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\folder\project.py", line 999, in <module>
    load_data()
  File "C:\Users\me\folder\project.py", line 124, in load_data
    globals()[var_name] = pickle.(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I get this error when trying to unpickle a file, even though the file is non-empty. I've tried opening the file and printing its value and it is non-empty, but the unpickler returns this result still.

Anyone know why this may be happening?

The code here is as follows:

```
files_to_load = ['var1','var2',...]
def load_data():
    for var_name in files_to_load:
        path = '{}.txt'.format(var_name)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                globals()[var_name] = pickle.Unpickler(f).load()
        else: globals()[var_name] = {}
```

Comment: It could be happening because the file contains invalid data.  But rather than having people guess, it would be better to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah starting to think the file was corrupted somehow. I have added the function in question @DennisSparrow

Comment: It's still not reproducible until you provide the code that wrote the file, or at least the contents of a failing file.  According to [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939913/how-to-test-if-a-file-has-been-created-by-pickle), there is no way to check if a file has valid content for unpickling other than trying to unpickle it.  However, the answer says the last byte of the file should be a STOP opcode, which turns out to be a period character ('.').  If that is supposed to be there and it's not, that could plausibly generate "Ran out of input."  You could check for that.